# How to find number of Subdirectories under a given directory

Tags: shell, directory, recursive

In windows you get a count of the number of subdirectories within a directory.Is there any equivalent on Linux ? 
I'd like it to count recursively & Not stop at a single level.

Comment: @HaukeLaging That question is not the same, note "I'd like it to count **recursively**..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `find` to count all directories in a tree starting from current directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

Note, that `-mindepth` is required to exclude current directory from the count.

You can also limit depth of search with `-maxdepth` option like this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

More `find` options are available. You can check man page for that,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get number of directories and files use this:

```
tree /path/to/given/dir | awk 'END{print}'
```

If you want only number of directories, add `-d` option:

```
tree /path/to/given/dir -d | awk 'END{print}'
```

tree works recursively.